# HashMap<Integer, Object> is assigning same value to all keys

Tags: java, object, hashmap

So I have this code here that creates an object called student that takes strings for name and major, and keeps track of total credits and quality points to calculate GPA. I'm trying to create a HashMap in order to be able to search students using the key (student ID) and get back the values held using the Student blueprint class. But my code is assigning the same value to all keys, the last student entered into the HashMap. Here's the code followed by the current output. Note this is a simplified version of my complete code, just to showcase the issue I'm having. Thank you to anyone willing to help!

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Test {
public static class Student {
    static private String name;
    static private String major;
    static private int totalCredits;
    static private int totalQP;

    public Student (String name, String major) {
        this.name = name;
        this.major = major;
        this.totalCredits = 0;
        this.totalQP = 0;
    }

    public static void courseCompleted (int grade, int creditHours) {
        totalQP += grade;
        totalCredits += creditHours;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        float GPA;
        if (totalCredits != 0) {
            GPA = (float) totalQP/totalCredits;
        } else {
            GPA = (float) 4.0;
        }
        return "Student name: " + name + "\nStudent Major: " + major
                + "\nStudent GPA: " + GPA;
    }
}

public static void main (String [] args) {
    HashMap<Integer, Student> studentDatabase = new HashMap();

    studentDatabase.put(1234, new Student("Default", "Default"));
    studentDatabase.put(7623, new Student("Phyllis Jones", "English"));
    studentDatabase.put(8729, new Student("Cletus Smith", "History"));
    studentDatabase.put(7321, new Student("Betty Booth", "Computer Science"));
    studentDatabase.put(3242, new Student("Samuel Seybright", "History"));
    studentDatabase.put(9823, new Student("Oscar Blue", "English"));
    studentDatabase.put(2341, new Student("Sally Grief", "Copmputer Science"));
    studentDatabase.put(8321, new Student("Jacques Matchel", "Mathematics"));

    System.out.println(studentDatabase.entrySet());
}
}
```

Output:
[8321=Student name: Jacques Matchel
Student Major: Mathematics
Student GPA: 4.0, 1234=Student name: Jacques Matchel
Student Major: Mathematics
Student GPA: 4.0, 2341=Student name: Jacques Matchel
Student Major: Mathematics
Student GPA: 4.0, 7623=Student name: Jacques Matchel
Student Major: Mathematics
Student GPA: 4.0, 8729=Student name: Jacques Matchel
Student Major: Mathematics
Student GPA: 4.0, 7321=Student name: Jacques Matchel
Student Major: Mathematics
Student GPA: 4.0, 3242=Student name: Jacques Matchel
Student Major: Mathematics
Student GPA: 4.0, 9823=Student name: Jacques Matchel
Student Major: Mathematics
Student GPA: 4.0]

Comment: don't use `static` fields.

Comment: More details.  Every instance of Student references the same four member values because they are declared as static.  Remove static from the Student member variables.

Comment: all your fields in class Student are static. remove static and everything should work

Comment: also i think you need this.name and this.major to the toString function

Comment: Fixed it. Love all of you. Sorry I'm terrible at coding honestly.